# How to create dynamic XML's from XSD iterating Dictionary keys?

Tags: java, python-3.x, xml, dictionary, xml-parsing

How to create dynamic XML's from XSD iterating Dictionary keys. I tried hard coding the values with following code. Need help how to iterate through the dictionary and create XML.

**CODE:**

```
import xmlschema
import json
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

my_xsd = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' \
         '<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' \           
         '<xsd:element name="ISA" type="xsd:string"/>' \
         '</xsd:schema>'

schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(my_xsd)
data = json.dumps({'ISA': '01'})


xml = xmlschema.from_json(data, schema=schema, preserve_root=True)

ElementTree(xml).write('D:/my_xml.xml')
```

**Input:**

```
{'ISA0': 'ISA', 'ISA1': '01', 'ISA2': '0000000000','ISA3': '01', 'ISA4': '0000000000'}
```

**Schema :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">         
<xsd:element name="ISA0" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Output:**

```
output.xml

<ISA0>ISA</ISA0>
<ISA1>01</ISA1>
<ISA1>02</ISA1>
```